# Make a set of images's brightness the same

Tags: python, opencv

I've got a set of images to feed into
https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/omz_models_model_person_reidentification_retail_0277.html

This model is very sensitive to brightness changes, so I want to make all images' brightness the same, how can I archive this?

Comment: Take one image as the standard and compute its mean and standard deviation. Convert all your images to HSV. Apply https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/06/30/super-fast-color-transfer-images/ between each image and the standard image, but only to the V channel. Then combine the new V channel with the old H and S channels and convert back to BGR. You may only want to do the mean part of the processing and leave the standard deviation alone. But you can decide.

Comment: Alternately, you could do histogram equalization to all the images.

Comment: Which one did you use?

Comment: histogram equalization adjusts only the contrast of the image